# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend' in django-admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When i start a new project using `django-admin startproject anil` i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\gsrnation\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\gsrnation\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\gsrnation\Desktop\sp\venv\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\gsrnation\desktop\sp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\gsrnation\desktop\sp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "c:\users\gsrnation\desktop\sp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\gsrnation\desktop\sp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "c:\users\gsrnation\desktop\sp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "c:\users\gsrnation\desktop\sp\venv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'
```

I have even made a virtualenv but still same error is comming. My django version is Django==2.0.5 and python version is python 3.6.5.
I tried running my previous django project but still same error is comming.

Comment: do you have an existing dajngo project in the same directory?

Comment: no I don't. I can't even create django project due to this error.

Answer (score 0):

GoodDay Brother,

Make sure that you have updated the new Django App name in your project settings.py file. The new App name should be in single quotes followed by a comma.

> INSTALLED_APPS = [
>       'newAppName',
>       'django.contrib.admin',
>       'django.contrib.auth',
>       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>       'django.contrib.sessions',
>       'django.contrib.messages',
>       'django.contrib.staticfiles', ]